# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need jQuery autocomplete for a project but it doesn't work for me.
I don't know where is my mistake.
Thanks in advance !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Votre titre</title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var liste = [
            "Draggable",
            "Droppable",
            "Resizable",
            "Selectable",
            "Sortable"
        ];

        $('#recherche').autocomplete({
            source : liste
        });
    </script>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="recherche" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open developers console, check for errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with html syntax here:

- Move the script tags for jquery files to the head tag
- move your script to after the body

Your script must be after the body tag or it can be placed instead of the head tag and use a document ready check to allow it to run after the page loads (see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Votre titre</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
      <form>
          <input type="text" id="recherche" />
      </form>
  </body>
    <script>
        var liste = [
            "Draggable",
            "Droppable",
            "Resizable",
            "Selectable",
            "Sortable"
        ];

       $('#recherche').autocomplete({
            source : liste
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

see a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/q7k28bp0/1/